# Memcpy overwrites area in 3 dimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memcpy

I am trying to make a little bash and parse the strings to a 3 dimensional array. The first indices is the cmd, the second the argument and the third the characters.

No my problem is, that when I memcpy the last argument, it writes it to the next command.

```
int main()
{
  char buffer[256] = {"c1 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 \n"}; 
  char arg_list[10][10][255];
//  fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);

  int c = 0;
  int index_cmd = 0;
  int index = 0;
  int index_arg = 1;
  int lastIndex = 0;
  int nxt_cmd = 0;

  for(c = 0; c < 255; c++)
  {
    if (buffer[c] == '\r' || buffer[c] == '\n' || buffer[c] == ' ')
    {
      if(index_cmd == 0 || nxt_cmd)
      {
        memcpy(arg_list[index_cmd][0], buffer + lastIndex, c - lastIndex);
        arg_list[index_cmd][0][c-lastIndex] = 0;
        index_cmd++;
        index_arg = 1;
        nxt_cmd = 0;
      }
      else if(buffer[c-1] == '&' || buffer[c-1] == '|')
      {
        memcpy(arg_list[index_cmd][0], buffer + lastIndex, c - lastIndex);
        arg_list[index_cmd][0][c-lastIndex] = 0;
        nxt_cmd = 1;
        index_cmd++;
        index_arg = 1;
      }
      else if(buffer[c-1] != ' ' && buffer[c+1] != ' ')
      {
        memcpy(arg_list[index_cmd-1][index_arg] , buffer + lastIndex, c - lastIndex);
        arg_list[index_cmd-1][index_arg][c-lastIndex] = 0;
        index_arg++;
      }
      lastIndex = c +1;
    }

  }

  int i,j,k = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    for(j =1; j < 11; j++)
    {
        printf("command %d %s\n",i,arg_list[i][0]);
        printf("arg %d %s\n",j, arg_list[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

The code example gives me the following output:

```
command 0 c1 
arg 1 a1
command 0 c1
arg 2 a2
command 0 c1
arg 3 a3
command 0 c1
arg 4 a4
command 0 c1
arg 5 a5
command 0 c1
arg 6 a6
command 0 c1
arg 7 a7
command 0 c1
arg 8 a8
command 0 c1
arg 9 a9
command 0 c1
arg 10 a10
command 1 a10
arg 1 
command 1 a10
arg 2 
command 1 a10
arg 3 
command 1 a10
arg 4 
command 1 a10
arg 5 
command 1 a10
arg 6 
command 1 a10
arg 7 
command 1 a10
arg 8 
command 1 a10
arg 9 
command 1 a10
```

So it writes argument10 to the place in the array where if provided the next command should be.

I really dont know whats the problem, but I think it has something to do with `memcpy`.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including the needed `#include` statements

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Comment: please clean up the code so it cleanly compiles.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to perform the same thing

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) please consistently indent the code.  Note 2 space indentation levels can/will be lost when using variable width fonts.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  3) Please separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line 4) insert appropriate space(s) inside parens, inside brackets, inside braces, after semicolons, after commas , around C operators

Comment: it is good programming practice to limit the scope of variables.  For instance regarding: `for( c = 0; c < 255; c++ )`  write it as: `for(size_t c = 0; c < 255; c++)`  Similar considerations exist for the other loops

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E.  10, 10, 255, 256.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C, the index to an array is 0...(number of elements in array-1). So regarding: indexes into

```
char arg_list[10][10][255];
```

the first index has range of 0...9

the second index has range 0...9

the third index has range 0...254.

Those areas in the posted code that are indexing outside the allowed ranges is an error and results in undefined behavior

Comment: Thank you very much for your good programming hints and answer! :)